# SPOJ 726 code: PRO Wrong Answer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, heap

link to question : http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRO/

**What I have done**

The question asks you to select the minimum and maximum element from the list and add it to the total, It used heapq module in python to solve the question, although it passed the provided test case, but gives a Wrong Answer after submitting.

**My Question**

What is Wrong in my code ?

**My code**

```
import sys
from heapq import *

n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
inp = []
total = 0

for _ in range(n):

    text = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().split()]

    k = text[0]

    del text[0]

    inp.extend(text)

    heapify(inp)

    while(len(inp)>=2):

        Max = inp.pop(-1)

        Min = heappop(inp)

        total += (Max-Min)

print(total)
```

Comment: The heap condition only guarantees that heap[0] is the minimum. There is no guarantee that the max is heap[-1].  It is probably an accident that the test case passed.  I suspect that if you randomized `4 10 5 5 1` in the right way, you might have 10 not at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just using a list rather than a heapq? Consider:

```
inp.sort()

while len(inp) >= 2:

    Max = inp.pop(-1)
    Min = inp.pop(0)
    total += (Max-Min)
```

Comment: The problem is more complicated than this -- more numbers are added on each of up to 5000 days.  I would note that Python's sort takes advantage of existing order, so extending an existing sorted list by a sorted list (for each day) and resorting is close to O(n).

Comment: It is also worth noting that after each day, one only needs to keep the k smallest and k largest numbers, where k is the number of days left in the promotion.  Anything in between will never by used.